# Querying for underscore character in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, definition-query, oracle-spatial

For a standard LIKE query against an Oracle-based ArcSDE feature class, the underscore character represents a single character wildcard when used with a string.

I'm trying to impose a definition query to find a text string that starts with 4 digits exactly followed by an underscore character.

Does anyone know how I would specify an underscore character itself in a query or if/what the escape character might be?

[MDHald's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/182289/115) works for file geodatabases but my case is specific to Oracle. Falsely assumed that ArcSDE and file geodatabase query would function the same for this case.

Comment: Escape character is usually a backslash `\ ` - I believe this is also the case with Oracle, so you'd want to look for `\_` if searching for the underscore.

Comment: @Midavalo, that was the first thing that came to mind. My query was CABLE = '_____\\_%'  , which returned zero results.

Comment: you might need to use `LIKE` (although you do mention LIKE in your question) - `CABLE LIKE '____\_%'`.  I'll have a play here although I'm using SQL Server rather than Oracle so may get different results

Comment: Try `CABLE LIKE '____\_%' ESCAPE '\'` - from [SQL reference for query expressions used in ArcGIS - Desktop Help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s500000033000000.htm)

Comment: @Midavalo, found the exact same thing right after you did

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Managed to track down the answer.

You can specify an ESCAPE character in query such as:

MY_FIELD LIKE '____$_%' ESCAPE '$'

This will search for exactly 4 characters followed by an underscore character plus anything else after that.

Found the documentation on this page: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/sql-reference-for-query-expressions-used-in-arcgis.htm

Not sure how far back or what versions this is valid for but it works for ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.

Excerpt from the documentation:

> *x [NOT] LIKE y [ESCAPE 'escape-character']*
>
> Use the LIKE operator (instead of the = operator) with wildcards to build a partial string search. The percent symbol (%) means that
>   anything is acceptable in its place: one character, a hundred
>   characters, or no character. Alternatively, if you want to search with
>   a wildcard that represents one character, use an underscore (_). If
>   you need to access noncharacter data, use the CAST function. For
>   example, this query returns numbers that begin with 8 from the integer
>   field SCORE_INT:
>
> *CAST ("SCORE_INT" AS VARCHAR) LIKE '8%'*
>
> To include the percent symbol or underscore in your search string, use
>   the ESCAPE keyword to designate another character as the escape
>   character, which in turn indicates that a real percent sign or
>   underscore immediately follows. For example, this expression returns
>   any string containing 10%, such as 10% DISCOUNT or A10%:
>
> *"AMOUNT" LIKE '%10$%%' ESCAPE '$'*

Answer (score 3):

You will need to employ CHAR_LENGTH  and SUBSTRING in order for this to work. It would look as follows:

```
CHAR_LENGTH ("yourfieldname") =5 AND SUBSTRING("yourfieldname", 1, 4) <> '_'
```

where yourfieldname = the name of your field.

Do not delete the "" in the code though. Copy as is and replace only the text yourfieldname.

Comment: Your answer works for file geodatabases, but I didn't realize that the underlying DBMS would be so picky. Oracle doesn't like the query.

Comment: Oracle gets a bit tricky with [DATABASE]..[TABLENAME] it requires those double points. If the query doesn't work as a definition you could always create a view (right click in your database>select New>select View>) in your SDE(Presuming you have one setup if you are pulling from Oracle) and then write out a similar query.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this Q&A which helped me to solve why I was unable to use a where clause on an ArcPy search cursor which could restrict the cursor to just those records which contained an underscore (`_`) in a particular text field.

By the time I found it I had already developed a code snippet to illustrate the problem so, rather than waste that effort, I have added the solution to it and am now posting it here to perhaps help a future visitor with the same problem.

The test uses a file geodatabase and was run at ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(r"C:\Temp","test.gdb")
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(r"C:\Temp\test.gdb","testFC")
arcpy.AddField_management(r"C:\Temp\test.gdb\testFC","testField","Text")
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(r"C:\Temp\test.gdb\testFC",["testField"])
cursor.insertRow(["ABCD"])
cursor.insertRow(["A_CD"])
cursor.insertRow(["XYZ"])
cursor.insertRow(["X_Z"])
del cursor

where_clause = "testField LIKE '%C%'"
print("Using where_clause of {0} to limit search cursor to print any values containing the letter C:".format(where_clause))
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(r"C:\Temp\test.gdb\testFC",["testField"],where_clause) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print(row[0])
print("This is the expected result :-)")

where_clause = "testField LIKE '%_%'"
print("\nUsing where_clause of {0} to limit search cursor to print any values containing an underscore (_):".format(where_clause))
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(r"C:\Temp\test.gdb\testFC",["testField"],where_clause) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print(row[0])
print("This is not what I was hoping for :-(")

where_clause = "testField LIKE '%$_%' ESCAPE '$'"
print("\nUsing where_clause of {0} to limit search cursor to print any values containing an underscore (_):".format(where_clause))
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(r"C:\Temp\test.gdb\testFC",["testField"],where_clause) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print(row[0])
print("This is what I was hoping for :-)")
```

The output is:

```
>>> 
Using where_clause of testField LIKE '%C%' to limit search cursor to print any values containing the letter C:
ABCD
A_CD
This is the expected result :-)

Using where_clause of testField LIKE '%_%' to limit search cursor to print any values containing an underscore (_):
ABCD
A_CD
XYZ
X_Z
This is not what I was hoping for :-(

Using where_clause of testField LIKE '%$_%' ESCAPE '$' to limit search cursor to print any values containing an underscore (_):
A_CD
X_Z
This is what I was hoping for :-)
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for that...waste so much time on "special" character workarounds and syntax.... hopefully I remember where to find it next time it comes up.